# Themosis framework wordpress - default pages give 404 status

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm testing the Themosis WordPress framework but I can't seem to wrap my head around on how themes work with this framework.

After installing my own theme I can see the files located in **htdocs/content/themes/theme-name**. When I make a little adjustment in let's say footer.php I can see those changes with a default page. However every page I request results in a 404 page. (header and footer gets loaded from the theme folder).

The **themosis** routes work just fine, I can load in my own view and logic here.

In order for like default content pages to work (instead of going to a 404), do I have to edit these theme files or do everything via route files?

- Steps to reproduce:

  1. Install according to documentention.
  2. Login to Wordpress admin and create a post/page
  3. View page and see a 404.

Comment: Please add more details of the issue that you are facing.Share the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Comment: I've done some more research. It seems every default wordpress route has to be redefined in your own routes file

Comment: Something new here about this topic? I've the same issue.

Comment: Here's where they write about routing: https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/routing/

Comment: Can't find anything about it in the docs

Comment: @PatrickVdPols, can you add the steps you did that we could follow in order to be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Added it, theres not much to it to be honest ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, it seems that you do need to manually setup your WordPress routes. Here's an example for Pages/`page` and Posts/`post`:

```
// I added these to routes/web.php

// If is_page(), loads htdocs/content/themes/my-theme/views/pages/default.blade.php.
Route::any('page', function ($post, $query) {
    return view('pages.default', [
        'page' => $post, // not required
    ]);
});

// If is_singular(), loads htdocs/content/themes/my-theme/views/blog/single.blade.php.
Route::any('singular', function ($post, $query) {
    return view('blog.single', [
        'post' => $post, // not required
    ]);
});
```

See [The WordPress `$post` and `$query` parameters](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/routing/#the-wordpress-post-and-query-parameters) and [WordPress routes](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/routing/#wordpress-routes) on the Themosis [Routing doc](https://framework.themosis.com/docs/2.0/routing/).

Comment: Thanks, had the same conclusion.